# PHP check empty variable or not

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query and an array where I put values to exclude. When I perform my query, I would like to test my variable.

```
If not empty ==> Display values
If empty ==> Display one time 0 result.
```

My SQL query gives in output these values:FGFR1e12, FGFR3e7, FGFR3e14

When I perform my php script, I manage to display values but it doesn't enter in the loop else when the variable is empty.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in my script ?

Here's my script:

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');
$VariantNContrib = "SELECT DISTINCT Reference FROM mytable";
$PerformVariantNContrib = mysqli_query($conn, $VariantNContrib) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
// Values to exclude are stored in an array
$arrayNoContrib = array(
    'FGFR1e12',
    'FGFR3e7',
    'FGFR3e14'
);
while ($rowVarNContrib = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformVariantNContrib)) {
    if (!in_array($rowVarNContrib["Reference"], $arrayNoContrib)) {
        $NContribList = '' . implode(',', $rowVarNContrib) . '; ';
        if (!empty($NContribList)) {
            echo '<br/>Variants:' . $NContribList . '<br/>';
        }
        else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: do a `var_dump()` of `$NContribList` to see what it contains. That should tell you why it's not working. Alternatively, just replace `if(!empty($NContribList))` with `if(!count($rowVarNContrib))` to check the number of elements in the array directly rather than looking at the string. Also, off topic, but I would urge you to tidy up your code so that the intentation is correct -- the messy layout of the code you've posted makes it really hard to read.

Comment: when `$arrayNoContrib = array('FGFR1e12', 'FGFR3e7','FGFR3e14'); var_dump($NContribList)` displays `nothing`. When `$arrayNoContrib = array('FGFR1e12');  var_dump($NContribList)` displays `string(7) "FGFR3e7" string(8) "FGFR3e14"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I dont know why you have used `implode` if i am right. You have a `array` in which you have some values and you are `fetching` some `reference` and if all are same then you are displaying 0 result and if not then you are displaying that refence number. Then Please once try this one.

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');
    $VariantNContrib="SELECT DISTINCT Reference FROM mytable";
    $PerformVariantNContrib=mysqli_query($conn,$VariantNContrib) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    //Values to exclude are stored in an array
   $arrayNoContrib = array(
    'FGFR1e12',
    'FGFR3e7',
    'FGFR3e14'
);
    $i = 0;
    while($rowVarNContrib =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformVariantNContrib)) {
        if (!in_array($rowVarNContrib["Reference"], $arrayNoContrib)) {
            $NContribList = trim($rowVarNContrib["Reference"]);
            if (!empty($NContribList)) {
                echo '<br/>Variants:' . $NContribList . '<br/>';
                $i++;
        }}

    }
      echo $i." results";
```

Comment: Hi @mamta, thx for your help. Your script works at my end :). I actually used implode in order to display my results variants as the following: `Variants: FGFR1e12;FGFR3e7;` and not repeating Variants each time and having all on the same line. So I cannot use implode ?

Comment: hey you can store variants in array and then use implode after while loop. to display your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:-

```
$arrayNoContrib=array('FGFR1e12', 'FGFR3e7', 'FGFR3e14');
while($rowVarNContrib =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformVariantNContrib)) {
  if(!empty($rowVarNContrib) && !in_array($rowVarNContrib["Reference"],$arrayNoContrib)){  // check $rowVarNContrib array is not empty
    $NContribList=implode(',',$rowVarNContrib); // remove empty string      
    echo "Variants: $NContribList"."<br>"; // remove earlier <br>      
  }else{
      echo "0 results"."<br>"; // add <br>
  }   
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi, thx for your script. I tested but unfortunatly, it also don't enter in the loop else when $NContribList is empty. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function does not return true for string which is single space. `" "`.

```
$NContribList=''.implode(',',$rowVarNContrib).' ';
```

In above code you've space at the end of the string and that is the reason **empty()** is returning `FALSE`.

Either remove that space from the string or use PHP [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Hi @Alok, thx for your answer. I tried to remove undesired space by using rtrim: `$NContribList=''.implode(',',$rowVarNContrib).'; ';
  $NContribList2=rtrim($NContribList);` but it doesn't enter in else loop :(

Comment: Also remove `;` in the string. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I also tried with your update answer `$NContribList=''.implode(',',$rowVarNContrib).' ';` it doesn't work either. If I remove a value from `$arrayNoContrib` it enters into the if loop but if I let the 3 values into `$arrayNoContrib` it never enters into the else loop :(